# Checking if an item present in an array in Solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays, uint256

I want to check whether a specific item is included in an array or not. For example, consider the following array.

`uint[] a = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Is there any way that I can get `true` if I have given 4, and get `false` if I have given 5 to check for inclusion in the array?

Comment: Yes, there is a way - iterate the array, return `true` if you encounter the desired item, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Is there any other way? Like in operator of javascript?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: And BTW, the "operator of javascript" (I suppose you mean `.includes`), is just a "shortcut". In terms of runtime, it performs the same number of computations.

Comment: Have in mind that Solidity is very primitive language when it comes to predefined operations. I also believe the solution provided by @goodvibration is the only existing one for this case.